# Pass JVM Args to a specific TestNG test

Tags: java, maven, automation, maven-plugin

I'm working on some Selenium test automation in which the majority of tests run successfully as is; however there are a couple that require specific JVM parameters to run successfully. Is there a way to say in the build configuration "these tests require this JVM argument; however these ones don't?"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding this block in your TestNG test suite.and clubbing the tests which you wana provide different VM arguments.

```
<testng>
   <jvmarg value="-Djava.compiler=NONE" />
   <!-- ... -->
</testng>
```

Comment: What do you mean by clubbing?

Comment: I am refering build.xml(ant file) if you can paste your .xml file here it would be easy for reference.In build.xml we can create seperate test suite target and we can provide VM argument for specific target.well this link would be helpful if you are running from maven http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Comment: I am not using ant. I'm using a maven Pom. With a maven surefire configuration. Sorry I should have clarified in my question.

Comment: Okay i will try and separate them into two suites and then post my Pom entry.